# Getting balance for wallet in React using Web3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask

React newbie here. Have an issue starting out, specifically with getting the balance of an address attached to a connected wallet.

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import web3 from "web3";

function App() {
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState("");

  async function requestAccount() {
    console.log("Requesting account...");
    if (window.ethereum) {
      console.log("Metamask Wallet Detected");
      try {
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });
        setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
        console.log(walletAddress);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error connecting Wallet");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Metamask Wallet Absent");
    }
  }

  async function getBalance() {
    const accounts3 = await window.ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    });
    console.log(accounts3[0]);
    const balanceInWei = web3.eth.getBalance(walletAddress);
    console.log(balanceInWei);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <button onClick={requestAccount}>Connect Metamask Wallet</button>
        <h3>Wallet Address: {walletAddress}</h3>
        <h2>Account Balance</h2>
        <button onClick={getBalance}>on</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I already figured out how to fetch the address but for some reason can't find how to get the balance, I see different results everywhere.

Comment: You are missing `await`